# Generic Delete in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have a generic delete method `DoDelete<MyTable>(int batchSize, MyDatabaseContext)`

This methods builds up ids (`List<int> deleteId`) upto the batchsize count and then I like to call

```
BulkDelete<T>(MyDatabaseContext, t => deleteId.Contains(t.RecordId))
```

However this approach does not work because its unaware that `<t>` has property `RecordId` (even though it will always be `RecordId` property).

I have also tried:

```
int rows = BulkDelete<T>(MyDatabaseContext, "RecordId in (100001,100002)");
```

This is actual method that does the delete, I have also an overload that accepts string predicate.

```
public int BulkDelete<T>(MyDatabaseContext context, Expression<Func<T,   bool>> predicate)
where T : class
{
    int rows = context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).Delete();

    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need generics in the first place here? Why not an interface that all your models can implement?

Comment: `int rows = BulkDelete<T>(MyDatabaseContext, "RecordId in (100001,100002)");` I think you are using EntityFramework in wrong way...

Comment: Also, your `BulkDelete` function accepts an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` but when you call it, you're providing a string. That can't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @mason says, you can create an interface with a `RecordId` property that all your entities implement, then your generic `t=>deleteId.Contains(t.RecordId)` will compile:

```
// The interface
public interface IRecordIdEntity
{
    int RecordId {get;set;}
}

// Sample Class
public class Person : IRecordIdEntity
{
   // implement the interface
   public int RecordId {get;set;} 
}

// Generic BulkDelete for IRecordIdEntitys
public int BulkDelete<T>(MyDatabaseContext context, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    where T : IRecordIdEntity
{
    int rows = context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).Delete();

    return rows;
}

// Sample call
BulkDelete<Person>(MyDatabaseContext, person=> deleteId.Contains(person.RecordId))
```

Now that `BulkDelete()` is restricted to working on types implementing `IRecordIdEntity` the predicate is always valid.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use interface to work with:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    long RecordId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should do so that every other Entity object (table) implement that interface:

```
//Example
public class Book : IEntity
{
    public long RecordId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author{ get; set; }
}
```

After that you could easily add constraint to your method:

```
    public int BulkDelete<T>(MyDatabaseContext context, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        where T : class, IEntity
    {
        int rows = context.Set<T>()
            .Where(predicate).Delete();

        return rows;
    }
```

And after that this call will be good to go because `t` is `IEntity`:

```
BulkDelete<T>(MyDatabaseContext, t=>deleteId.Contains(t.RecordId))
```